# need to know ID or Name of form input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Using jQuery autocomplete..   Want to replace "hello" in script below with javascript to identify either the "name" or "id" of the input field...  (Will have several instances on a single page, so I'm not using ID, only class...)

```
    $(".suggest").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            console.log(request.term);
            $.ajax({

                url: "http://www.mysite.com/suggest/",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    'q': request.term ,
                    'r': "hello"
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },


    });
```

Comment: if a form has both an `[id]` and a `[name]` which takes precedence?

Comment: Wait ... if you're not using "ID" then what does it mean for you to want the id?

Comment: @zzzzBov the "name" is the only thing that matters for the form as far as posting to the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I remember it should be this.element:

```
$(".suggest").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var name = $(this.element).attr('name');
        console.log(request.term);
        $.ajax({

            url: "http://www.mysite.com/suggest/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                'q': request.term ,
                'r': name
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't ask me why this is not really documented anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Is it as simple as below?

```
$(this).attr("id") || $(this).attr("name")
```

Comment: The two are not substitutes for each other so I would never want to risk mixing them. Name is not unique, for an example of an issue that can arise from this.